# javascript fetch to IP address without http in url

Tags: fetch

I need to post data to local IP address with fetch like this:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/xml");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
fetch("192.168.1.5:11443", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

But fetch thinks it is not absolute address so id adds prefix. I cannot add http because server doesnt accept it.

I am using postman and it works there but cant make it work in my frontend.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an absolute address, you need to have `protocol://` (`http://` for instance), unless it's the same protocol as the current one (i.e. the one of your website), in which case you can simply use `//`.

Try this: `//192.168.1.5:11443`, that will be evaluated to `http://192.168.1.5:11443` if your website runs with HTTP and `https://192.168.1.5:11443` if it runs with HTTPS.

Comment: when i use postman and examine the code it uses fetch("192.168.1.5:11443", requestOptions) and it works. When i add http in postman server doesnt respond. I wanted to copy the code to my frontend but it doesnt work.